# invalid command name "Queue/LTEQueue"

Tags: error-handling, ns2, lte

I`ve installed lte in ns2.35 but it gives the folowing error:
invalid command name "Queue/LTEQueue"
    while executing
"Queue/LTEQueue set qos_ true "
    (file "lte.tcl" line 21)
 when i run lte.tcl

please hepe meto solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error: You are using a (wrong) copy of 'ns' with no LTE, or you have a failed build.

LTE, Howto ....

```
$ tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0

```
$ cd ns-allinone-2.35/
$ patch -p0 < LTE-ns235_2014-2.patch
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNLVlDZ29EWWxJTFk/view?usp=sharing

```
$ ./install
$ cd ns-2.35/
$ sudo make install ('make install' will copy the executable 'ns' to /usr/local/bin/)
$ cp ns ns235-lte   ( This is your backup and the recognizable "lte ns" )
$ sudo cp ns235-lte /usr/local/bin/
$ cd ../nam-1.15/
$ sudo make install
```

The examples : lte-examples-0614.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNRWV4Mzc0bGYtQzA/view?usp=sharing

Run some examples:

```
$ ns235-lte bicfixdownlink.tcl 
$ ns235-lte deVacto-lte.tcl
$ ns235-lte 24_downl413.tcl
```

EDIT : New example package, lte-examples-06.17.tar.gz, added `24_downl413.tcl`, etc. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSmd4Q3h3dXp1QWc/view?usp=sharing

And ns-allinone-2.35: `gt-itm` updated → `ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz`
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is there a patch for ns2.29?Can you give it?

Comment: See the answers here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ns-users/1aot_dOfAUg