# Implement an NS2 LTE simulation with sumo and Ad-hoc network

Tags: adhoc, ns2, lte, sumo

Hello everyone I want to ask for your valuable help to see if it is possible to add a SUMO scenario I have into NS2 to be able to simulate an ad-hoc network between cars and also allowed them to communicate with an LTE radio base station (eNodeB).
I already have SUMO and NS2 with the LTE patch running, I was able to add the LTE features thanks to an answer given by Knud Larsen in this post:

[invalid command name "Queue/LTEQueue"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603529/invalid-command-name-queue-ltequeue)

Comment: There are a couple of LTE examples included in `Vanet-examples-July14.17.tar.gz` → `LTE-802.11p-examples/` → The traffic , movement files are from SUMO https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNc1VnQ0hDSkZIUkU/view?usp=sharing  All ~2500 simulation examples https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

Comment: The LTE example L-guindy-teatinos40A.tcl is already connected with SUMO files, flowmod-teatinos-M40.tcl and mobmod-teatinos-M40A.tcl from http://neo.lcc.uma.es/staff/jamal/vanet/?q=node/11 ....  The trace file can be analyzed with APP-Tool https://github.com/WiNG-NITK/APP-Tool → throughput, etc.

Comment: The original example `urban-VANET-example.tcl` is an OLSR simulation. Please use the ~LTE example L-guindy-teatinos40A.tcl, which also works with your `mobility-1.tcl` (When the node number is set to 50, and the range to 2000 x 2000.) .... The edited file `1H-L-guindy-teatinos40A.tcl` https://www.dropbox.com/s/t9hml8owiy9usor/1H-L-guindy-teatinos40A.tcl?dl=0

Comment: ? What do you mean ? The file 1H-L-guindy-teatinos40A.tcl has `source activity-1.tcl` , and your link shows activity.tcl . ... Which OS are you using ? ? Please specify, like Ubuntu 16.04 - amd64, CentOS 6.9 - i386 , etc. etc.

Comment: Well the activity.tcl file I show you is the one that got created with my mobility.tcl file after getting the file ready from my SUMO project using this command: traceExporter.py --fcd-input unam.sumo.xml --ns2config-output unam.tcl --ns2mobility-output mobility.tcl --ns2activity-output activity.tcl and my OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with this specifications Intel Core i3-3120M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 ,64-bit. What could be the problem?@KnudLarsen

Comment: Well, your file copy here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0KAEW9TOkDvekZxRkFWa3ZnLXM still says `source activity-1.tcl`, so which file is used ? ... With activity.tcl : `can't read "g(0)": no such variable` .... Another thing: This link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0KAEW9TOkDvckotN25jM1ZDaXc ... is not a shared link : No access.

Comment: I ordered mi project into a folder here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0KAEW9TOkDvekZxRkFWa3ZnLXM I used the the files you shared with me and I'm trying to adapt my project to that, I have a new sumo project with only 10 cars to make it easier to see whats going on, what I'm trying to do is to be able to see and analyze how LTE and 802.11p work together in that specific scenario, the thing is that I get an error (the error is in the same folder I share in this comment named as "Error I get")unless I edit the number of nodes to 50 but I only have 10 cars @KnudLarsen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref. your note "7" https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0KAEW9TOkDvekZxRkFWa3ZnLXM

Your file `unam.tcl` :

```
set val(nn)             9
... change to
set val(nn)             11     ;# maximum number of nodes
             # nn must be higher than the node number in traffic, movement files :
             # any higher number can be used
```

It is forbidden to have two files with the same file name. unam.tcl is now named `unam11.tcl`, and mobility.tcl is `mobility9.tcl` .

Your file unam.tcl (`unam11.tcl`): No node higher than `$node_(10)` can be used. Your file line 111

```
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(22) $sink
... change to e.g.
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(3) $sink
```

Traffic file and movement files can also **not** exceed node numbers of 10 :

```
57  set opt(cp)     "flowmod-teatinos-M40.tcl"  ;# Network workload
.... must be e.g.
57  set opt(cp)     "flowmod-urban-malaga-S10.tcl"  ;# Network workload

... And
103 source mobility.tcl
104 source flowmod-teatinos-M40.tcl
.... can be
103 source mobility9.tcl
104 source flowmod-urban-malaga-S10.tcl
```

(The numbers are line numbers.) Other traffic files with max 10 nodes : cbr10, cbr-10-1-10-20 . And new traffic files with 9 .. 10 nodes can be created with e.g. `$ ns cbrgen.tcl [options]`

Traffic files etc. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNa3ZPQjB3UHo3cWc?usp=sharing

My test : `$ ns235-LTE-64 unam11.tcl` : 'nam' opens OK, the files unam.nam 43.1MB, unam.tr 31.9MB are created.

EDIT : An 802.11p file was omitted in your example, unam.tcl . New example = `unam11-802.11p.tcl`, with the connected 802.11p file = `802.11p-2.tcl`.  Link → https://www.dropbox.com/s/yofht7p5h2kk068/unam11-802.11p.tcl_files.tar.gz?dl=0

What is left out may be some LTE communication, see LTE examples https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSmd4Q3h3dXp1QWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok the project is finally running, thank you for the line for line detailed explanation, I share the correction to you for your verification in this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0KAEW9TOkDveGtGTWxlTGVwcmM I have some questions about what is doing, for example I see in the animation that node 3 is continuously sending something to a specific node and to be honest I don't quite understand where is the LTE base station and what is happening in the simulation. I believe that what I say about node 3 has to do with line $ns_ attach-agent $node_(3) $sink

Comment: Please see my edited answer. .... Note : The file activity.tcl is not used. What's the idea with activity.tcl ?

Comment: ok I corrected the projected and added the 802.11p-2.tcl file I believe that file contains the parameters that 802.11p is using I have the corrected project in this link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0KAEW9TOkDveGtGTWxlTGVwcmM for your verification, the activity.tcl file was a file that I generated from my Sumo simulation but I see that it does not have a use in this, I still don't get what's happening in the simulation I include an image with 2 things I don't understand and if its not an LTE base station why does the code says Queue/LTEQueue/DLAirQueue

Comment: You could read ... and run all the LTE examples https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSmd4Q3h3dXp1QWc/view?usp=sharing ... then you may find the information you are looking for.

Comment: Im running a simulation with the 802.11p-2 file you gave me but Im finding that some nodes in the simulation are sending Hello messages but not receiving the HelloReply message, is it posible for you to explain each field in the 802.11p-2 tcl