# File tcl is empty

Tags: python, ns2

please when i put this command in the terminal "`./traceExporter.py --fcd-input guindy.xml --ns2mobility-output high.tcl`" the result  file is empty

please what is the solution ?

[image]

Comment: It says `KeyError: 'orig-ids'` as the immediate error; the `further` dict doesn't contain that key. I don't know what the provenance of that dict is, so it could just be a simple programming error on your part.

Comment: Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914810/implement-an-ns2-lte-simulation-with-sumo-and-ad-hoc-network → https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0KAEW9TOkDveGtGTWxlTGVwcmM?resourcekey=0-dGezX5xaaOib91BukfyatQ >>> `$ python3 traceExporter.py --fcd-input unam.sumo.xml --ns2mobility-output high.tcl` → the file high.tcl , 189kB is created.